# Can't install language pack

Tags: localization, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to install italian language pack on a VM instance with Debian. I've tried almost everything but it still can't find the language pack.

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install language-pack-it-base
$ apt-get install language-pack-it
```

It returns:

```
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-it
```

It's the same with other languages.
Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install language-pack-it-base:

$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-it-base/language-pack-it-base_14.10+20141020_all.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i language-pack-it-base_14.10+20141020_all.deb

To install language-pack-it:

$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-it/language-pack-it_14.10+20141020_all.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i language-pack-it_14.10+20141020_all.deb

Verify the installation of the packages using dpkg -l

$ dpkg -l | grep language-pack-it

‘ii’ status indicates a successful installation.

If you get dependency errors during the installation, run the command below and re-install the packages.

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a