# Instaling lang pack on debian circular dependency

Tags: localization, debian, dpkg

I have problems installing language packs on debian
I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26940856/3202194
(I followed that because apt returns E: Unable to locate package language-pack-sk)
so I downloaded latest packages for sk and sk-base a tried to install them using dpkg

but i get this when i try to install sk

```
Unpacking language-pack-sk (1:16.04+20160415) over (1:16.04+20160415) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-sk:
 language-pack-sk depends on language-pack-sk-base (>= 1:16.04+20160415);
```

and this when sk-base

```
Unpacking language-pack-sk-base (1:16.04+20160415) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-sk-base:
 language-pack-sk-base depends on language-pack-sk (>= 1:16.04+20160415);
```

How do I install lang pack when there is circular dependency ?? (btw I need to instal more then sk, but I suppose it will be same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if you only do "apt-get install" then after confirmation prompt it will install both at once 
(all downloaded and not fully packages at once)
solving circular dependencies